# How to limit a Int field to a range of values?

Tags: haskell

In my Data

```
data User = User { uRank :: Int, uProgress :: Int }
```

I want to limit `uRank` to a list of values [-1, 1, 3], for example.

How do I do this?

Comment: Is this not simpy what you could do with an enum and use a function that maps it to ints if you want to do arithmetic on them?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Defining a small sum type is the best answer for this specific question. You can also use `newtype` with smart constructors to achieve this effect.

```
newtype Rank = UnsafeMkRank { unRank :: Int }

mkRank :: Int -> Maybe Rank
mkRank i 
    | i `elem` [-1, 1, 3] = Just (UnsafeMkRank i)
    | otherwise = Nothing
```

Now, provided you only use the safe `mkRank` constructor, you can assume that your `Rank` values have the `Int` values you want.

Comment: Smart constructors are often used in conjunction with module export lists:
module MyMod(Rank,myRank) where..
will not export the constructor UnsafeMkRank, disallowing you from using it in other modules, in case you (or other users) ever forget how to make good Rank.

Answer (score 8):

For something so small, you should define a precise type:

```
data Rank = RankNegOne | RankOne | RankThree  -- There are probably better names
data User = User { uRank :: Rank, uProgress :: Int }
```

Haskell doesn't force you to encode everything as a subset of the integers; take advantage of it!

For larger subsets where this would be unwieldy, you are looking for a *dependent type*, which (until recently?) is not supported by Haskell directly.

Comment: Is it possible to show a quick example of dependent type in use here? Indeed there are quite many values for the rank value.

Comment: It's possible, but not be me :) I was attempting to veil my ignorance by being vague.

Comment: It's Okay. At least it's a good pointer. I'll dig a little deeper

Comment: @osager and others.  For a refinement type example please see my answer using Liquid Haskell.

Answer (score 5):

Liquid Haskell, which adds refinement types on top of Haskell, can do this.  See the correct section of the tutorial [here](http://ucsd-progsys.github.io/liquidhaskell-tutorial/05-datatypes.html).

First you define your data type as normal.

```
module User where

data User = User { uRank     :: Int
                 , uProgress :: Int
                 }
```

Next we define your restriction as a refinement type.  Liquid Haskell users comment annotations with syntax `{-@ blah @-}`.  We'll define your odd restriction of `-1, 1, 3` first with the `RestrictedInt` type:

```
{-@ type RestrictedInt = {v : Int | v == -1 || v == 1 || v == 3} @-}
```

That is, the `RestrictedInt` is an `Int` that is either `-1`, `1`, or `3`.  Notice you could easily write ranges and other restrictions, it doesn't have to be some mindless enumeration of legitimate values.

Now we re-define your data type in our refinement language using this restricted int type:

```
{-@ data User = User { uRank     :: RestrictedInt
                     , uProgress :: Int }
  @-}
```

This is similar to your definition but with the restriction type instead of just `Int`.  We could have inlined the restriction instead of having a type alias but then your `User` data type would be pretty unreadable.

You can define good values and the `liquid` tool will not complain:

```
goodValue :: User
goodValue = User 1 12
```

But bad values result in an error:

```
badValue :: User
badValue = User 10 12
```

`$ liquid so.hs` (or your editor's integration, if you have that setup) produces:

```
**** RESULT: UNSAFE ************************************************************


 so.hs:16:12-18: Error: Liquid Type Mismatch

 16 | badValue = User 10 12
                 ^^^^^^^

   Inferred type
     VV : {VV : GHC.Types.Int | VV == ?a}

   not a subtype of Required type
     VV : {VV : GHC.Types.Int | VV == (-1)
                                || (VV == 1
                                    || VV == 3)}

   In Context
     ?a := {?a : GHC.Types.Int | ?a == (10 : int)}
```