# How to do bounds-checking in haskell at compile-time?

Tags: haskell, types

I am rather new to Haskell and I was wondering how one would go about enforcing bounds using the type-system. After reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7302735/how-to-create-a-type-bounded-within-a-certain-range) and checking out the linked article on [smart constructors](https://wiki.haskell.org/Smart_constructors) I think I get how you could generate a bounded type and generate a constructor for it  like in the example:

```
data Probability a = P a deriving (Show, Ord, Eq)
```

I read in [learn you a Haskell for great good](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses), that you should

> never add typeclass constraints in data declarations

so no type-constraints at this point...

```
instance Bounded Probability where
  minBound = P 0
  maxBound = P 1     

smartP :: (Floating a) => a -> Probability
smartP x = assert (0 <= x && x <= 1) $ P x
```

What I am wondering now is if and how it would be possible to do the bounds-check at compile-time for a type that is not easily represented in terms of [Peano numbers](https://wiki.haskell.org/Peano_numbers) (like Double...). And maybe if possible, how one would go about finding an encoding for non-enumerable but bounded types.

Furthermore: Probabilities are numbers, and I would like them to behave like numbers (have + - * etc. work on them as you would expect). Is it possible to achieve this behavior by making `Probability` part of the `Number` type-class (via deriving or some other way that doesn't involve coding all the functions by hand in the obvious way)?

Thanks a lot for any explanations.

Comment: `data Probability = P a` doesn't make sense. Either choose a concrete, fixed type for the implementation, i.e. `data Probability = P Double`, or make the implementation a parameter, i.e. `data Probability a = P a`. Theoretically it is also possible to “entomb” a type variable in a concrete, unparameterised container (_existential type_), but I'm quite sure this is not a good idea for what you want. — And BTW, you should probably make that a `newtype` instead of `data`, for performance.

Comment: "How do I do bounds-checking at compile-time for a type that is not easily represented in terms of Peano numbers (like Double)?" In fact, the answer to this is completely independent of whether your type is easily representable as a Peano number. The answer is: reimplement your type (like Double) and all the operations you care about at the type level. (Good luck with that! I already know that's more man-years of effort than I'm willing to put in for a few points on StackOverflow.)

Comment: Sometimes one can enforce constraints in the type system (see e.g. Okasaki) but, in general, this is not always feasible, at least not without starting a research project on that precise goal. Such a large effort would better be spent on improving the type system, e.g. by adding refinement types, which could help to move more constraints into the type system.

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41743056/how-to-limit-a-int-field-to-a-range-of-values/41749649#41749649 ?

Comment: Notice what you are asking for requires lots of proof work across the uses of your `Probability` type.  For example, you can't simply say `newProbability = old1 + old2` without first proving that those two total less than or equal to `1`.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Thanks, overlooked that (as I said, new to Haskell...) going to edit.

Comment: @DanielWagner OK, the answer "No there is no way to do this easily/automated" would be perfectly acceptable to me. If you want you can elaborate on your comment in an answer. I was just wondering about it and given what you said I would agree that its probably not worth it. Can you estimate if and how much this might gain in performance?

Comment: @Chris You've got it backwards. This is going to lose big in performance -- probably a 100x slowdown or worse.

Comment: @DanielWagner Thanks for the nice explanations. So your advice is "Do not mess with type-level constraints but working with 'smart-constructors' should do fine". Is that about a fair summary?

Comment: @Chris Yes, I would say in Haskell smart constructors are much lighter-weight in development time and runtime. Additionally, though they require a little bit of (non-machine-checked) careful attention to module boundaries, after that is done they do provide most of the benefits a purely type-level solution would.

Answer (score 1):

*Interpreting your question as **"What is the best way to represent probability such that invalid states are not representable"**, and riffing on that. I'm not an expert and don't know if this will help you.*

---

Let's assume (maybe incorrectly) you are originally computing probabilities from samples. Your `successes` and `tries` are both integers in memory. Let's even assume they are arbitrary precision (in haskell `Integer`).

Except for the fact that they can be computed quickly, IEEE floating point is not a good way to represent probability (see [here](http://funcall.blogspot.com/2008/07/probability-and-floating-point.html)):

- they become less dense as you move from 0 to 1.0, and so if you care about precision you cannot freely transform between the *probability of a thing happening and it not happening*
- it's wasteful: most representable values lie outside your 0 - 1 range

From the blog post I linked above, we learn that working with odds instead of probability improves the situation (we double the number of useful values), and in particular *log-odds* solves the first issue above by "stretching the dense regions of floating point numbers and compressing the sparse regions."

### Odds in log space

*Most info related to log-odds I learned in [this nice write-up](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/34547557/log-probability.pdf) byt Brian Lee and Jacob Sanders*

*log-odds* is simply the logarithm to some base of the odds (so we use `logOdds` where we'd use `/` if we wanted probability). We can play around with it in ghci and get an intuition pretty quickly:

```
Prelude> let logOdds successes tries = logBase 10 ( successes / (tries - successes))
Prelude> logOdds 1 2
0.0
Prelude> logOdds 1 10
-0.9542425094393249
Prelude> logOdds 5 1000
-2.2988530764097064
Prelude> logOdds 995 1000
2.2988530764097064
Prelude> logOdds 99995 100000
4.301008280396999
Prelude> logOdds 9999995 10000000
6.3010297785166856
```

We can see the whole float domain is useful now, and we can convert between *likelihood* and *unlikelihood* without losing precision. There are also arguments that it's easier to make decisions based on intuition with these numbers.

So `log-odds` is representation isomorphic to probability where invalid states are not representable. We can convert back with

```
Prelude> toProbabilty lgOdds = (1 - (1 / (1 + (10**lgOdds))))
Prelude> toProbabilty 2.2988530764097064
0.995
```

#### Working with log-probability

I'm not sure how convenient this is or what you're trying to do with your probabilities. The link above mentions that log-odds works naturally in the context of Bayes theorem.

But I wanted to elaborate on this, because *log-odds* is an instance of a general technique I generally hear called "working in log space" which can be very helpful when trying to do calculations where you might get very large or very small values. The idea is to use the log laws to transform your calculation, to lower multiplications and divisions to additions and subtractions.

I'm out of time and will try to come back to this later, but observe

```
odds successes tries = successes / (tries - successes)
odds successes tries = 10 ** (logBase 10 ( successes / (tries - successes)))
odds successes tries = 10 ** (logBase 10 successes - logBase 10 (tries - successes)
```

my goal if I had more time being to show hopefully how a ratio representation of probability can be used for some calculations you might be interested in, without losing precision.

### conclusion

Part of my point of this answer is that we don't usually need to do type-level computation to make invalid states unrepresentable. When we return `Either Foo Bar` from a function we're doing this.

Another example in a library I wrote I originally had a comment that the user should only pass on `Int` that was a power of two, otherwise error. Instead I changed the function to take the power of two directly.

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer, the probabilities was just an example... I assume there is a nice package to handle probabilities in a satisfactory way. There are just so many things you might want to represent like distances and so on that are bounded but not enumerable.