# Define Function with Constraint on List's Elements?

Tags: haskell

How can I define a function with the following signature,

```
f :: [Int???] -> [Int]
f xs = _ -- what I do with xs doesn't matter for the question
```

where `a` is a List of `Int`'s

such that the first argument's inputs, i.e. list elements, must be `>= 0`, but `<= 5` at compile-time?

In other words,

`f [6]` would fail to compile.

Comment: i guess youu cant. By the type signature, your function must accept any integer.

Comment: This signature won't allow that. You'd need a custom datatype or dependent types (not in Haskell... yet ;)).

Comment: Updated my question to indicate that the first argument's type doesn't have to be `[Int]`, but the output must be `[Int]`.

Comment: in this case you actually can... check out the article on smart constructors: https://wiki.haskell.org/Smart_constructors There is an example given how you can model valid list elements using  phantom types and Peano numbers. you can also check out the comments here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43896822/how-to-do-bounds-checking-in-haskell-at-compile-time

Comment: Previously, on SO: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43896822/791604), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41743056/791604), [3](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7978191/791604), and probably many more.

Answer (score 5):

How about:

```
f :: [Int] -> [Int]
f = filter (\x -> x >= 0 && x <= 5)
```

Or do you want to enforce the bounds on the type (dependent types)?

If you want to restrict the range of the `Int` that is allowed you are probably better of using a *smart constructor*. Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7978191/how-to-make-a-type-with-restrictions). The idea is that you create your own datatype and your own custom constructor:

```
newtype Range0_5 = Range0_5 { unRange :: Int }

makeRange0_5 :: Int -> Maybe Range0_5
makeRange0_5 x
  | x >= 0 && x <= 5 = Just $ Range0_5 x
  | otherwise        = Nothing
```

If you make a *smart constructor*, it is important to not expose it to the user of the module. This can be done by simply not exporting the `Range0_5` constructor.

However this is not a compile time check. Other languages than Haskell might be more appropriate if you really need such a feature.

Since the range is fairly small, you could also make a sum type to represent it:

```
data Range0_5 = Int0 | Int1 | Int2 | Int3 | Int4 | Int5
```

Comment: Edited question - my mistake for not specifying at compile-time!

Comment: Edited answer, hope it helps. :-)

Comment: If you go for the custom type I would recommend making it an instance of the `Enum` type-class, this way you get the "natural" mapping from your custom type to the Ints for free...

Comment: Welp, I wanted to post an answer with exactly what you wrote in the edit, so +1.

Answer (score 1):

If the signature is

```
f :: [Int] -> [Int]
```

(which was the original form of the question), then it is impossible to enforce your constraint at compile time. This follows from the standard [diagonalization argument of the Halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).

Suppose the compiler could detect that

```
f[g x]
```

should not compile. By incorporating the source code of the compiler into `g`, it could choose the opposite of the compiler's decision.

---

Following your comment on [Liquid Haskell](https://ucsd-progsys.github.io/liquidhaskell-blog/) (which seems like a very interesting project), note the following:

```
{-@ type Even = {v:Int | v mod 2 = 0} @-}

{-@ foo :: n:Even -> {v:Bool | (v <=> (n mod 2 == 0))} @-}   
foo   :: Int -> Bool 
foo n = if n^2 - 1 == (n + 1) * (n - 1) then True else foo (n - 1)
```

LiquidHaskell claims this function is unsafe, because, potentially `foo n` calls `foo (n - 1)`. Note, however, that this will never happen: it will only be called if the relationship *n<sup>2</sup> - 1 ≠ (n + 1) (n - 1)*, which can never happen.

Again, this is not a criticism of the quality of LiquidHaskell, but rather just pointing out that it, too, cannot solve Halting Problem like issues.

Comment: LiquidHaskell can't help me in this problem?

Comment: @KevinMeredith Thanks for the link - it is a very interesting project. I addressed it in the answer.